# Mongo inserted _v field in C#

Tags: c#, json, mongodb

I'm trying to inserting data to MongoDB using C#, JObject, and BSONDocument without defining any model (direct JSON).
Maybe this is possible duplicate from [How to remove _v and _t from mongo document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49307482/how-to-remove-v-and-t-from-mongo-document) and [How to prevent _t and _v when inserting into MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42943709/how-to-prevent-t-and-v-when-inserting-into-mongodb) , but I can't find my answer.

But there's _t and _v field. And the value that i put before, stored in _v field as an object.

Here's the code

```cs
var mongo = new MongoClient(new MongoUrl("mongodb://localhost"));
var db = "test";
var database = mongo.GetDatabase(db);
dynamic obj = new JObject();
obj["coy"] = "haha";
BsonDocument c = BsonDocument.Parse(obj.ToString());
database.GetCollection<dynamic>("test").InsertOne(c);
```

and the result

```
// 1
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5ca5ace48d93c485ce90bb43"),
    "_t": "MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument, MongoDB.Bson",
    "_v": {
        "coy": "haha"
    }
}
```

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't define a model for this? I suspect the problem would simply disappear if you did. The `_t` and `_v` values (which I suspect stand for _type_ and _value_ respectively) are just the inner logic of the dynamic type being dumped straight into the database.

Comment: Because the user input is dynamic. And if I make a model for it, it'll going to be about 30+ model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `BsonDocument` as the collection type:

```
database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("test").InsertOne(c);
```